# Fiddler 4.4.9.1, is it possble to show only hosts with a [-dev.]

Tags: fiddler

I am trying to limit fiddler to showing me requests to a web server similar to this:

- static-dev.example.com

I used "Help->Troubleshoot Filters..." to ensure the traffic was actually happening.

I am setting filters in filters tab. I have "Show only the following hosts" selected and ensured the "Use Filters" checkbox is check.

Filters I have tried:

- static-dev.example.com
- *.example.com
- *example.com

Results:

- static-dev.example.com is always hidden

If the hostname doesn't contain the string "-dev" everything works as expected. I try setting my filter to "Hide the following hosts" to narrow things down but the list got unwieldy very quickly.

Note:

- The filter "www.example.com" is working as expected.
- The filete "static-content.example.com" is working as expected

Comment: `*.example.com` should work fine. Click `Troubleshoot Filters`, find a session in the list that is unexpectedly struck-out, and look in the `Comments` column. What do you see?

Comment: "Hidden due to FiltersTab>UrlMatchedHideIfList. Hidden due to FiltersTab>UrlMatchedHideIfList. Hidden due to FiltersTab>UrlMatchedHideIfList. Hidden due to FiltersTab>UrlMatchedHideIfList. Hidden due to FiltersTab>UrlMatchedHideIfList. Hidden due to FiltersTab>UrlMatchedHideIfList. "

Comment: Looks like I had set "Hide url if it contains..." D'oh. Pilot error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Filters->Request Headers check "Hide if URL contains". Ensure it is not checked/doesn't match the problem URL.